# Pie charts in QGIS: attributes generated with Expressions not working when using aggregate function

Tags: qgis, select, expression, aggregation, chart

I have a problem to add values generated by expressions with aggregate functions to pie charts (see the screenshot below for better understanding). This question is a follow up question to [this one here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382596/draw-graph-in-qgis-on-selection-of-multiple-points). In QGIS (using 3.16), you can [add pie charts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=pie%20charts#diagrams-properties) from a vector layer / Properties. This works perfectly as long as you select existing attribute values for the pie "slices" (circle sectors): see the two selected attributes (red rectangle) on the screenshot below - they render as expected on the map canvas.

Further, the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=pie%20charts#attributes) also mentions that

> Generated attributes with Expressions can also be used.

However, when I try to add such generated attributes with expressions, consisting of an aggregate function (`sum`) on the basis of all selected features (`is_selected`), no output is generated: see the entries in the blue box on the screenshot. I tried other aggretage expressions like `aggregate`, with no success. Using expressions without the aggregate and `is_selected` criteria, it works as expected.

The expression like `sum ( "data_protestant", filter:=is_selected () )` is correct and works in other contexts: I can use it to generate pie charts with geometry generator using the expression `wedge_buffer` - however, this is cumbersome if you have several values the visualize. And the built in pie charts creator clearly offers the possibilities to use expression based values.

Thus the question is: Is the direct rendering of such pie charts (expression based, aggregating over several features under the condition they are selected) a limitation of QGIS or can this be overcome somehow?

This here is a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/335768/sub-expression-not-considered-when-using-aggregate-functions-qgis-3-8), however the answer did not resolve the problem.

[image]